# Tag name for MMU, SAFER, and similar?

Tags: discussion, tags

What would be a good tag name for devices that help propel a spacewalking astronaut?  Such devices include the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manned_Maneuvering_Unit), [SAFER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_Aid_For_EVA_Rescue), and the canned gas that Ed White used during his spacewalk.  I have a pending question for the "jet boots" that were considered for Skylab.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

[astronaut propulsion unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronaut_propulsion_unit) or * maneuvering * ? I'm not exactly in love with that, but haven't thought of a better one.

Comment: `astronaut-propulsion` seems like an okay variation, if nothing else better is suggested.

Comment: `astronaut-articulation`? (humor)

Comment: @DrSheldon I'm fond of that too.